# The usage of cflags and simflags

Tags: openmodelica

When use **Openmodelica shell**, and when use command **simulate(Model)**, actually I noticed the method **simulate(ModelName, ..., ..., cflags, simflags)** has a lot of arguments. But what is the **cflags** and **simflags**?

I tried to find details in **userguide** and all other documents on the official website, and use google to search, but I can not find details.
So, is there any tips? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

With cflags you can add additional flags which are used by the c-compiler  to create the executable based on the mo files.
for example you can add additional include directories if you have user defined functions.

The **simflags** are described there: https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/simulationflags.html

For an example the following command runs the simulation with the time step size given by the integration algorithm DASSL:

`simulate(NMBS.Samples.Pendulum2,simFlags="-noEquidistantTimeGrid");`